# Jcalender Customize and add Text in Specific Date Cell in Swing java

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

I am working on Swing. and i got one problem while working.

i have to Display some text on Jcalender Date  specific Date cell. is there any way to do it? i am using Jcalender

thank you for your response in advance.

Comment: Which Jcalendar?  Provide a link to the specific Jcalendar you are using.

Comment: [tag:jcalendar] is a date chooser, not a day planner; your application should store this in its model for display in your (chosen) view.

Comment: But how to store this and ya how to Customize this can u just give me Example Code.?? please i am hardly need of that.

Comment: and i am using this one http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/